# Request.Form is empty (asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been doing some really clever stuff (I think) in ASP.Net c#, so much so that the simple stuff is more difficult (if that makes sense)

I have this snippet of code in my page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnConfirm" value="Hello World" />
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="/confirm.aspx" Text="Confirm">
    </asp:LinkButton>
</form>
```

I have this snippet of code in `confirm.aspx`.

```
if !(IsPostback)
{
    lblConfirm.Text = Request.Form["hdnConfirm"]
}
```

I was expecting this to be nice and simple but when i click the button and go to page "confirm.aspx" the Request.Form has no values. What have I missed ?

[TESTING]

I ran a test on a brand new web forms project in VS2013. Dot.Net 4.5.1 This does not work. `PreviouPage` is always null. Whether surrounded by `(!IsPostBack)` or not. Doesn't matter if the submitting control is a `Button`, `LinkButton` or `Hyperlink`. `Request.Form["hdn"]` is also null. I have restarted my computer just in case and still no joy. I am missing something really simple I am sure of it but I can't see what

This is the first page nothing in the code behind

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/WebForm2.aspx">click</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn" Value="3" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the second page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = ((HiddenField)this.PreviousPage.FindControl("hdn")).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if !(IsPostback)` is invalid syntax.  Even assuming you mean `if (!IsPostback)` then that would only work on first page entry, not on the post-back?

Comment: Are you sure the control is called `hdnConfirm` in the rendered HTML? Have you tried `Request.Form[hdnConfirm.UniqueID]` instead?

Comment: Examine the post request using the development tools in the browser.  Verify that the posted data is there and that the fields have the names you expect ("hdnConfirm").  I'm guessing that the name of the HiddenField is not "hdnConfirm" at all.  The name is what counts.

Comment: Can you check what is inside your `Request.Form` with `lblConfirm.Text = Request.Form.AllKeys.Aggregate("", (current, key) => current + ("<b>" + key + ":</b> " + Request.Form[key] + "<br/><br/>"));`

Comment: Did that too. There is nothing in the collection, its empty, doing a Quick Watch shows `AllKeys {string[0]} string[]`

Comment: I tried your code and my `AllKeys` property shows 7 elements and contains `hdn` . I am using `VS2013`. Are you starting web site from `WebForm2` ?

Comment: That's exactly what I was expecting. The website starts from `WebForm1` as it has the button on it

Answer (score 2):

On `confirm.aspx` use `PreviousPage.FindControl` instead :

```
HiddenField hdnFieldName = this.PreviousPage.FindControl("hdnConfirm") as HiddenField;
string hiddenValue = string.Empty;
if (hdnFieldName != null)
{
    hiddenValue = hdnFieldName.Value;
}
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) is good example to get you started.

Comment: Should have said I tried that and it doesn't work either. I have done this before and I've checked my other code and can't see anything different.

Comment: [UPDATE] PreviousPage is null every time

Comment: @user985197 I just tried above in an empty solution and works perfectly I get "Hello World" as value of hiddenfield - I am calling above code in Load

Comment: See my comment and updated question. this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**What's going on Here:**
By default with VS 2013 and Asp.Net v4.5.1 , there is a feature [**`FriendlyUrls`**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx) which is enabled.

The FriendlyUrls feature does kind of Asp.Net routing , thus changing URLs from `localhost/webform1.aspx` to `localhost/webfrom1`

`PostbackUrl` property will not work in combination with Asp.Net Routing. When ASP.NET routing is in use the `PreviousPage` URL is the final routed URL. The runtime will check for a file represented by the Routed URL now, which will be `webform1` and NOT `webfrom1.aspx`. Since there is NO such file as `webform1`,  so it will always set the `PreviousPage` to `null`.

**Possible Solutions:**

So, now you know the issue at hand.

1.) Either don't use the Routing system of Asp.Net Friendly Urls , in this case, therefore try adding the `<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/WebForm1.aspx"%>` to `webform2.aspx` page and check.

2.) OR if you keep the FriendlyURLs and hence the Routing system, make changes in your code to read the Form values using some other alternatives.